# DOORS DXL link to non existent object in module Baseline

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm currently having a problem with dealing with linking between two modules with different baselines.

Example:
I have a module A with 10 baselines and module B with 10 baselines.
Links are out links from A => B. The last baseline of module A has been done 1 month after the last baseline of module B. In the meantime more objects in module B have been created and were linked from module A to them.

So now I have some links in the last baseline of module A that link to objects in module B that are non existent in the last baseline of module B (only are existent in the last baseline++).

When I run my DXL-Script in order to get all linked objects I also get the IDs of these non existent object eventhough they do not exist in the last baseline. I open both modules and load the last baseline with the load(module, baseline,false) function. The name of the baseline works and my debugging shows me that I'm really working on the latest baseline. But somehow these non existent objects are listed because of the linking. I've read something about echoed links but they do not work for me.

A possible solution would be to get the Date of the baseline of module A and compare it with the creation date of the linked object. But there must be an easier and cleaner way imho... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that I do not have a direct answer to your question. I tried a script between two modules (A and B) like you presented. I linked the objects, made a new baseline, and added a few more objects that was also linked up.

I do not meet the problem you presented when I run the following script. I hope there could be something that gives you a new idea. Basically I open a baseline of Module B and count in-links. Newer objects (which I find in current version) are not included in this count.

```
Module modB = read("/Testmappe/ModuleB", false)
Module baselineModuleB
Object objB
Link l
string linkModName = "*"
int countLinks = 0

  // baseline(MAJ, MIN, SUFFIX)
Baseline myBaseline = baseline(0, 1, "")

if(baselineExists(modB, myBaseline))
{
  baselineModuleB = load(modB, myBaseline, false)

  for objB in baselineModuleB Module do {
    for l in all(objB<-linkModName) do {
    countLinks++
    }
  }
  print "Number of in-links are: " countLinks ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. It should actually work but only counts the in-links of the module. The problem is more that if I follow an out-going link it would lead to a non existent object. I did now a workaround were I check the "Created By" Attribute and compare it with the Date of the Baseline of Module A. It seems that the date of the link is currently my only chance.